# Does Chebyshev's inequality sacrifice a little power for simplicity?

Tags: self-study, probability-inequalities

I followed the proof in Chapter 2 of Ross Introduction to probability and statistics for Engineers.

As follows;

Chebyshev inequality
For any K > 1 ( for K< 1 still holds for 0<K_1 but trivial )

1. Where $S_k = {i, 1 \le i \le n : |X_i - \bar{x}| < ks}$
   s being the standard deviation.
   $\frac{\left|S_{k}\right|}{n} \geq 1-\frac{n-1}{n k^{2}}>1-\frac{1}{k_{2}}$

**Proof**

Use algebraic identity

2. $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i ^2- n\bar{x}^2$
3. Use variance definition
   $s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2$
4. $ (n-1)s^2 =\sum_{i \in S_k} (x_i-\bar{x})^2 +\sum_{i \not\in S_k} (x_i-\bar{x})^2$
5. $\ge \sum_{i \not\in S_k} (x_i-\bar{x})^2$ from 4.
6. $\ge \sum_{i \not\in{S_k}} k^2s^2$ from 1 since we are using the complementary set
7. which  is $ k^2s^2(n-|S_k|)$ restatement of 6

so

8. ${(n-1)s^2} \ge k^2s^2(n-|S_k|)$
   divide by $nk^2s^2$
9. $\frac{n-1}{nk^2} \ge \frac{n-|s_k|}{n}= 1 - \frac{|S_k|}{n}$
10. $\frac{|S_k|}{n} \ge 1 - \frac{n-1}{nk^2} $ since we can add $\frac{|s_k|}{n}$ and subtract $\frac{n-1}{nk^2}$ on both sides.

I think the statement at 10 is more powerful because a slightly bigger percentage of the data would be captured inside the k standard deviations.  Why do we not learn it that way?

Comment: The Chebyshev bounds are tight in the sense that there's a distribution at which you can approach the bound arbitrarily closely for each k > 1. If course if you add any information/conditions, different bounds may then apply.

Comment: Thank you. What does "tight" mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds#Tight_bounds (i.e. more or less as I loosely describe immediately after I say "in the sense that")